# Costs for developing an Iphone physics game?

Tags: physics, iphone, costs

I recently made a game demo inspired by a wooden board game where you drop the ball trying to make a score, is fully playable so take a look (Works best on firefox):
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62131673/LuckyBall-Chrome/index.html

I want to build this game for the Iphone's App Store, add accelerometer features, menus, unlockable levels, best scores, etc. I'm a graphic designer so I prefer to keep working on the presentation (graphics, assets, sound, music) and leave the rest to the programmer.

I want to know how much this game would cost for a programmer to be developed, so I can make a video at kickstarter.com and sell the idea, with luck this game will see the light.

I don't want to open a debate on the subject, I just need advice on the costs so I can hire someone.

Comment: There is no general answer to that. But in US/Europe you start from around 30$ per hour for a more/less unexperienced programmer up to more that 150$ per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a programmer to make a time estimation you would need to have a [requirements specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Requirements_Specification). My advice is to make one of these and ask different programmers what they would charge to get it done. A junior developer might need more hours but will cost less per hour and vice versa for a senior one.

Another route which may suit well for you is to specify functionality for different iterations which you could then present as options on the kickstarter. This will also help you to determine high priority tasks.

I wouldn't venture a guess at total hours or cost with only the information given.

The game looks fun, good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

the costs would mainly be with the iOS developer license which is $99/year and the an apple computer to use xCode. you can use 3rd party applications but xCode is the apple approved coding SDK.

Comment: I'm asking for the costs of hiring a developer to do the programming job for iOS.

Comment: that can very depending on there terms. there's no way to set a price as every developer charges a different price.

Comment: the cost of the license would be a very small sliver for what the cost of developing the game would be. Even with an apple computer the cost wouldn't touch the development cost.